# How to save results as xml in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssms

I am trying out TDD and creating fake objects, I want to use XML from the test DB. Thus I want to create XML of the results of a query, which I am running in SQL Server Management Studio.

But I am unable to find how to get the results as XML in SQL Server Management Studio. Is this possible? And How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use "`FOR XML`" to output the results of a query to XML.

For example:

```
SELECT
     o.Order_Number AS 'OrderNumber', --Element
     o.Order_Total AS '@OrderTotal' --Attribute

FROM dbo.ORDER o
FOR XML PATH('ORDER'), ROOT('ORDERS') --Path / Root let you formulate the xml the way you want
```